# How can I integrate users from two different Office 365 accounts into one Teams instance?

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-office-365, office365, microsoft-teams

Our company has about half our users on one Office 365 account and all on the (say) example1.com domain, and the other half on a totally separate Office 365 account example2.com.

We want to start using MS Teams and need some way to "link" these two accounts. I am aware that it's possible to invite users from one to the other as "guests" but this would be painful and there's serious limitations to doing that.

(Also worth noting it's NOT really practical for us to combine the two Office 365 accounts into one which hosts both domains; that would be the simplest solution of course but isn't viable.)

Is it possible to do something to make the Active Directory servers for each account cooperate so that we can present a single, unified MS Teams environment with full functionalty for all users?

Comment: When you say "account" you mean "tenant", right?

Comment: AFAIK, guest access is really the only way to achieve this - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/communicate-with-users-from-other-organizations

Comment: Thanks I think you're right that "tenant" is the correct terminology here - thanks.Thanks for the link. Although "guest" access is what I'm trying to avoid having to do, as it just makes things awkward and complicated.